# how to Drag UIImage from scrollview to View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop, draggable

I create 5 Uiimage inside scrollview

and want to Drag  Uimage from scrollview to view  to Back image (bottom)

But I can't make it

Anyone can help me for code or easy example please

PS. I make on storyboard

http://www.uppic.org/share-66B4_54093656.html

Comment: not clear in understanding your query.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side from images of all of your view controllers that are in storyboard, you can see list of them. There, for each view controller you can see hierarchical list of its components. There you can select that UIImage and move it on the view you need to.